# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome_model extends CI_Model {

      public function select(){

                  $this->db->get('av_home');
                  echo $this->db->num_rows();

      }
}
```

Above code gives error,

> Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()

Answer (score 7):

The number of rows returned by the query.With `num_rows()` you first perform the query, and then you can check how many rows you got.

`$query` is the variable that the query result object is assigned to:

```
 $query=$this->db->get('av_home');// assign to a variable
 echo $query->num_rows();// then use num rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Welcome_model extends CI_Model {

      public function select(){

            echo $this->db->get('av_home')->num_rows();

      }
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.