# Codeigniter num rows error

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i run this code it's working fine

```
  echo $str = $this->db->last_query();
```

After this line

```
 if($selectRecords->num_rows()>0){
 //some action
}
```

I'm Gating this error

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows() in <b>/vagrant/application/controllers/applicationtable.php</b> on line <b>1240</b><br />
```

This is my code

```
<?php
    public function xyz(){
            $selectRecords=$this->db->select(" (SELECT name FROM $this->reportTable WHERE id=$this->reportType) AS `$this->reportLabel`, 
                        SUM(rashi_given) AS `total` ,
                        SUM(rashi_accepted) AS atotal");
              $selectRecords->join('type', 'applicants.type=type.id', 'left');
              $selectRecords->group_by($this->reportType); 
              $selectRecords->get('applicants');
             echo $str = $this->db->last_query(); 
          if($selectRecords->num_rows()>0){

           }
     }


    ?>
```

What's the problem please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the wrong variable. See [Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625729/call-to-undefined-method-ci-db-mysql-drivernum-rows)

```
$rs = $selectRecords->get('applicants');
echo $str = $this->db->last_query(); 

if($rs->num_rows()>0){

}
```